# Weather.com api: Possible to exclude webcam where images cannot load?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, weather-api

I have a C# MVC website that calls the weather.com api on the backend, passes the data (as a JSON -> C# POCO) to the front end as a model, and process what I need in the view.

It is possible to have the weather.com API return a list of local webcams. In each webcam class object, there is a property called `Currentimageurl` which contains, surprise, a url for a webcam image.

I have noticed that a few of these don't show up. Very specifically, when you attempt to navigate to those directly, you get an access denied error similar to the following:

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId><...some number here></RequestId>
    <HostId>
        <...long string of characters here>
    </HostId>
</Error>
```

All other images show as you would expect. And, very specifically, the same images repeatedly give an access denied error when you attempt to load them or navigate to them.

The question is either:

1. Why am I getting an access denied error and what can I do about it?

OR

2. Is there a way to determine which images are giving me an access denied message and omit them from the front end rendering? In case it's important, C# on the backend, RAZOR and javascript/jquery on the front. These are being embedded into a bootstrap carousel (with indicators and images generated in a `foreach webcam`) so the indicators and images must be kept in lockstep with the correct "slide to" adjustments made for images which deny access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not the fastest solution, it has the virtue of working and only taking about 6 seconds to parse the 45 web cam urls. I'm sure it could be optimized but here is the initial solution:

```
public void ValidateWebCams() {
    if (Webcams == null || Webcams.Length == 0) {
            throw new System.Exception("Webcams not populated!");
    }
    List<Webcam> newWebCamList = new List<Webcam>();
    foreach (Webcam cam in this.Webcams) {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(cam.Currentimageurl);
        try {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)(request.GetResponse());
            newWebCamList.Add(cam);
        }
        catch (WebException ex) {
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response; //in case I want to examine this
        }//end catch                  
    }//end foreach
    this.Webcams = new Webcam[newWebCamList.Count];
    int loopCounter = 0;
    foreach (Webcam cam in newWebCamList) {
        this.Webcams[loopCounter++] = cam;
    }
}
```

To summarize, we loop through each webcam in the array, grab the url and just hit it, looking for the web response from it. If it's a 403 (access denied), it throws and hits the catch. If it throws, we really don't care about it. If not, however, we add it to the new web cam list. Once we iterate the whole collection, we wipe the existing webcam collection and replace it with the ones that did not 403.